# Read multiple strings from a file C++

Tags: c++, ifstream, stringstream, getline, file-read

I need to read different values stored in a file one by one. So I was thinking I can use `ifstream` to open the file, but since the file is set up in such a way that a line might contain three numbers, and the other line one number or two numbers I'm not sure how to read each number one by one. I was thinking of using `stringstream` but I'm not sure if that would work.

The file is a format like this.

```
52500.00       64029.50      56000.00
65500.00       
53780.00       77300.00     
44000.50       80100.20      90000.00      41000.00    
60500.50       72000.00
```

I need to read each number and store it in a `vector`.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Reading one number at a time even though each line contains a different amount of numbers?

Comment: Are the numbers all supposed to end up in one big vector, or one vector per line?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special, the regular stream extraction operator (`>>`) skips over all whitespace automatically, so spaces and newlines will be treated the same.

Comment: Do you need to process each type of line differently? Are they related number on each line that need storing in different places, or is it just a strangely formatted list of single numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not read them as numbers from the file?

```
double temp;
vector<double> vec;
ifstream myfile ("file.txt");

if (myfile.is_open()) {
  while ( myfile >> temp) {
    vec.push_back(temp);
  }
  myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: hmm i was doing something close to this, but yeah it's better to just read them as numbers. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about position of numbers I propose using [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/) after [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) :

```
std::ifstream f("text.txt");
std::string line;
while (getline(f, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while(iss) {
        iss >> num1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<double> v;
ifstream input ("filename");
for (double n; input >> n;) {
  v.push_back(n);
}
```